# How do I change part of the URL without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this url: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=123456

How do I replace the **123456** part without reloading the page?

I found the replacestate option but from what I understand it replaces the whole URL, not just the part of the URL that I want.

Comment: So just compose the entire new URL from the current one and the new number

Comment: `const newURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.pathname + "?returnurl=" + n;`

Answer (score 3):

```
window.history.pushState({}, 'title' , window.location.href.replace('123456','not123456'));
```